# Naming a function in javascript for-loops

Tags: javascript, function, for-loop, naming

I need to create a loop that prints out the numbers 1-75 excluding multiples of 7 and replacing them with a quote. What I need help with is that I need to name the function (ex: forLoop).

this is my code, is it correct?

```
var forLoop= function() {
    for (var i= 1; i < 76; i++) {
        var skip = 0;
        if (i % 7 == 0) {
            console.log("Not all who wander are lost");
            skip = 1;
        }
        if (!skip) {
            console.log(i);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You should consider using `if (i % 7 == 0) { … } else { … }` instead of that `skip` variable. Which should be a boolean anyway instead of a number, shouldn't it?

Comment: How does the title relate to the question?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you're just missing a closing brace (for the function) and the invocation:

```
var forLoop= function() {
    for (var i= 1; i < 76; i++) {
        var skip = 0;
        if (i % 7 == 0) {
            console.log("Not all who wander are lost");
            skip = 1;
        }
        if (!skip) {
            console.log(i);
        }
    }
};

forLoop();
```

Comment: Beat me to it! Also, there's no reason to put this in a function.

Answer (score 0):

@Trott's answer is great, but just for the lols, here's a coffeescript one-liner to do the same thing:

```
(if i % 7 is 0 then console.log "Not all who wander are lost" else console.log i) for i in [1..76]
```